# edit a json file using ouput of another multi line file

Tags: json, shell, sed, jq, jenkins-groovy

I have a json file and i need to edit it using value from some other file. The file whose value needs to be applied to the json file is a multi string file

Here i am using a jenkins groovy shell to output the contents of a file xyz.txt to a variable called file that can be used to edit the json file.

```
sh '''file=`cat xyz.txt`
      printf '{ "body": "" }' > myfile.json
      sed ...................
'''
```

Now using the above i have a json file like the below

```
{ "body": "" }
```

But i would like to replace the empty quotes "" next to "body" with the value from the output of xyz.txt which means the value of ${file} and is hence a multi string with separate lines.

How do I do that, probably using sed or something else?

Comment: Look into `jq`.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to use jq to get this done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given -R/--raw-input and -s/--slurp flags together, jq makes input file's content accessible through `.` filter. This can be used for your purpose like this:

```
jq -Rs '{body:.}' xyz.txt > myfile.json
```

Answer (score 0):

With just Groovy, you can load the json and the other file, change the content of the loaded json as you like and then write the changed json out.  E.g.

```
def myjson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse("/tmp/myjson.json" as File)
myjson.body = ("/tmp/xyz.txt" as File).text
def result = groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(myjson)
println result
// ⇒ {"body":"TEST\n"}
```